# SBS 2003 Event ID 3005 (ActiveSync Related)

Tags: exchange-2003, activesync

I've recently noticed the following Error in my Server logs. Happens whenever Mobile device user attempts to syncrhonise using OMA. The error is logged on the server, but the user is able to sync, albeit slowly.

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   Server ActiveSync
Event Category: None
Event ID:   3005
Date:       16/03/2010
Time:       01:22:20 PM
User:       xxxxxx
Computer:   xxxxxx

Description:
Unexpected Exchange mailbox Server error: Server: xxxxxx 
User: xxxxxx HTTP status code: [409]. Verify that the Exchange 
mailbox Server is working correctly.
```